# Останавливается служба (Service) при закрытии приложения Android

Tags: java, android

Пол дня мучаюсь и не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы сервис не убивался при закрытии приложения? Попробовал многие методы из интернета, ничего не помогает совсем. Служба всё равно останавливается.

MyService.java:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // проверяем в фоне все время работы экрана
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);

        // фильтруем на появление флага выключения экрана
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);

        // если это так то запускаем рессивер
        mReceiver = new LockScreenReceiver();

        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Служба запущена",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Служба остановлена",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Сам сервис запускается так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);

startService(intent);
```

Manifest:

```
<service
       android:name=".MyService"
       android:enabled="true"
       android:exported="true"
       android:process=":MegaLockerProcess">
</service>
```

Comment: startForegroundService, и в самом сервисе нужно это подтвердить при открытии, плюс разрешение вманифесте

Comment: @Style-7, а какое разрешение в манифесте? Можно примеры? Уже задолбался, ничего не выходит.

Comment: @ModaL добавил разрешение в низ своего ответа

Comment: android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для создания сервиса, который не будет убит системой необходимо, чтобы этот сервис постоянно поддерживал уведомление.

Пример такого сервиса:

```
class MyForegraundService : Service(){
    companion object {
        const val channelId = "--your channel id--"
        const val notifyId = 395 // some number
    }

    private val notificationBuilder
        get() = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
        else NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.d("Your service started")
        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? = null

        override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        sendStartNotification()
        doWhatYouNeed()// your code
    }
}
```

Где sendStartNotification:

```
private fun sendStartNotification() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) createChannel()
    val notification = buildNotification()
    this.startForeground(notifyId, notification)
}

private fun buildNotification(): Notification {
    val builder = notificationBuilder

    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_6)
            .setContentTitle(this.resources.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(this.resources.getString("describe process"))
            .setShowWhen(true)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setProgress(100, 0, true)
            .priority = NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX
    return builder.build()
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private fun createChannel() {
    val manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    val name = getString("notification_channel_name")// for user
    val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
    channel.description = getString("notification_channel_description") //for user
    manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
}
```

Пример где можно почитать: https://www.dev2qa.com/android-foreground-service-example/

Гуглится по запросу ForegroundService.

Если простыми словами, то такой сервис будет жить до тех пор, пока висит уведомление, а уведомление создается несмахиваемым. Очевидно, перезагрузка устройства сервис убьет. Так же бывает, что система убивает даже такой сервис, но это случается нечасто (на практике пока ни разу встретилось), а пользователь имеет возможность увидеть, что сервис убит. При остановке сервиса нужно убрать/заменить уведомление.

Всё вышеописанное вполне справедливо и для сервиса, запускаемого в другом процессе, как это делаете Вы.

P.s. Совсем забыл про разрешение в манифесте:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

В манифесте у сервиса должно быть прописано

```
android:stopWithTask="false"
```