# Android выполнение задач с заданной периодичностью

Tags: java, android

Имеется необходимость выполнения одной и той же задачи с нужной периодичностью даже когда приложение закрыто или устройство было перезагружено. Необходимости висеть постоянно в процессах в виде службы нет (узнал что для API 26+ проблемно реализовать работу службы когда приложение закрывается).
Прошу подсказать как можно реализовать то что мне нужно, буду благодарен если предоставите ссылку с примером реализации.

Comment: либо в виде службы (service) вместе со всеми трудностями, либо очень грязные хаки (ненадежные и потенциально закрываемые гуглом). Уверены, что службы не подходят? Там всё не так сложно. И еще, что за задача? Для некоторых вещей есть отдельные способы

Comment: загрузка нескольких интернет-страниц -> обработка html страницы -> вывод уведомления при необходимости. и это нужно делать с заданной периодичностью

Comment: тогда это однозначно foregraund service. Недавно я отвечал на вопрос про него https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1105431/365775

Comment: Пробовал, с API 26+ при закрытии приложения убивается и сам сервис. Вот к примеру VK как то же мониторит наличие входящих сообщений

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/background, посмотрите в сторону WorkManager или AlarmManager

Comment: @vip72 значит что-то не так делали, я недавно на работе такое делал - 8, 9, 10 андроид - все работает замечательно

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov я тестировал Foreground и все испробовал, к сожалению не удалось заставить работать, вот тут похожая проблема https://www.cyberforum.ru/post13638747.html

Comment: @vip72 уточню, Вы точно отправляли в шторку несмахиваемое уведомление из сервиса на всё время работы?

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov я не совсем опытный, но по моему да, я отправлял несмахиваемое уведомление, можете ознакомиться с кодом тут https://yadi.sk/i/mUgp-itu3bNuDg заранее извиняюсь за кривой способ
У меня телефон на Андроид 8, при закрытии приложения служба моментально умирает (Xiaomi Redmi 6)

Comment: @vip72 с ходу ошибок не вижу... а в манифесте permission указали?

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov да, FOREGROUND_SERVICE стоит

Answer (score 1):

Задача решилась на Android 8 следующим путем:

Все таки воспользовался Foreground Service, оказалось помимо permissions нужно вручную зайти в настройки телефона и включить автозапуск для моего приложения + работу в фоновом режиме

Comment: телефон случайно не Redmi ?

Comment: @Wlad да, Redmi 6

Comment: тогда твоя проблема лишь в том, что это Redmi, а точнее оболочка MIUI) и как ты верно описал - надо было включать автозапуск вручную. на других устройствах, если все написано верно, такой ошибки не должно быть. во всем виновата дурацкая MIUI, которая очень плохо дружит с любыми фоновыми задачами: сервисы, AlarmManager, ресиверы и тд и тп. а точнее - блокирует их работу если посчитает нужным (а она так посчитает в 99% случаев).